# Update drop down selection with radio button selection using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So this is a follow up to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974217/convert-dropdowns-to-radio-buttons-w-o-modifying-html). I need to replace some dropdown menus with radio buttons without modifying the HTML. In the post I linked earlier, someone came up with a really clever Jquery solution that successfully replaces the dropdown menu with radio buttons and updates the dropdown selection when one of the radio buttons is selected.

However, when I implemented it with the plugin, the radio buttons appear but they don't update the drop down's value when selected. I suspect there is some conflict with js elsewhere on the page but after some trial and error, I still can't figure out whats going on. Any ideas? The site in question can be found [here](http://designvillain.com/dev3/?page_id=4&shopp_pid=1)

Here is the [original solution](http://www.jsfiddle.net/yJTdF/) from the earlier post

So here is the updated code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(function(){
    $("#options-1 option").each(function(i, e) {
        $("<input type='radio' name='r' />")
        .attr("value", $(this).val())
        .attr("checked", i == 0)
        .click(function () {
            $("#options-1").val($(this).val());
        })
        .appendTo("#r");
       $("#options-1").change(function(){
       $("input[name='r'][value='"+this.value+"']").attr("checked","checked");
});
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have this function in addition to your existing code

```
$("#d").change(function(){
    $("input[name='r'][value='"+this.value+"']").attr("checked","checked");
});
```

Comment: So I added the updated code to my op but it still doesn't seems to update correctly.

Comment: try using '#options-1' instead of '#d'. Here is working code   http://jsfiddle.net/ChinmayeeG/TkGP8/

Comment: Hmm, still no luck, I wonder if this is some sort of conflict.

Comment: First of all don't bind change method inside foreach loop. It will bind change method n [no. of options you have in dropdown] times. Keep it outside the loop. Secondly, check whether you have unbind method for $("#options-1"). Also check you are biding change method only once to your drop down throughout the code.

Comment: Ahh it was the foreach. Thanks - got it!