# Control dropdown menu with radio buttons without modifying html

Tags: jquery, radio-button

So this question is actually an update related to previous question [Update drop down selection with radio button selection using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975331/) from a couple years back. I have come across a similar situation in which I need to product radio buttons to replace dropdowns but I cannot modify the html/jquery/ajax.

Using the above method I have been able to get this working which has been wonderful. However, I am hitting an issue along the way that I've been struggling with for days now. Upon clicking the first radio option the second group loads but only the first radio button (in this case representing "select option;n"), yet when the same radio button from the first set it clicked again all options appear as they should. I can't figure out why the function fires correctly on second click but not the first. Here is the website for reference http://www.amymatto.com/product177.html and here is my updated radio button code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
$("#menu_1 select option").each(function(i,e) {
$("<input type='radio' name='sizeopt'/>")
    .attr("value", $(this).val())
    .attr("checked", i === 1)
    .click(function() {
        $("#menu_1 select").val($(this).val()).trigger('change');
                $("#coloropt").empty();
}).appendTo("#sizeopt");
$("#menu_1 select").change(function(){
    $("input[name='sizeopt'][value='"+this.value+"']").attr("checked","checked");
    $("#menu_2 select option").delay(800).queue(function(i,e) {
    $("<input type='radio' name='coloropt'/>")
         .attr("value", $(this).val())
         .attr("checked", i === 0)
         .click(function() {
             $("#menu_2 select").val($(this).val()).trigger('change');
    }).appendTo("#coloropt");
    $("#menu_2 select option").dequeue();
});
});
});
});
$("#menu_1 select").change(function(){
    $("input[name='sizeopt'][value='"+this.value+"']").attr("checked","checked");
});
</script>
```

I'm fairly new to using jquery so please forgive any mistakes in the block. I might be completely off but my assumption was that if I empty the div containing the coloropt inputs on click and set a delay to producing the color opt inputs it would clear everything out and give the change function time to process the ajax request. I am using the

```
.trigger('change')
```

To fire the onchange from the dropdown menu and all seems to be working...but it takes two clicks? I'm stumped, anyone have any thoughts on this or catching something in my code that might be causing it to miss the first time?

Thanks guys!

Comment: It would really help if you put this in a fiddle

Comment: edit* [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yJTdF/167/) Everything seems to work fine - but once the ajax request comes into play something happens...the default page load contains no options for menu_2 until a selection from menu_1 is made.