# Change value title of a converted dropdown to radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I am using the following script ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a31p2371/16/)) to convert dropdown list to button selection.  But it displays the text of the button from the `value` of the option.

Is there a way to change the text displayed for each button, without changing the value of the button? Like giving it an `id` (getElementById) or something?  So the new buttons are like: `Option 1`, `Option 2`.. etc.

Current code:

```js
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975331/update-drop-down-selection-with-radio-button-selection-using-jquery
// http://jsfiddle.net/ChinmayeeG/TkGP8/
$(function () {

  $('.radioSelect').each(function (selectIndex, selectElement) {

    var select = $(selectElement);
    var container = $("<div class='radioSelectContainer' />");
    select.parent().append(container);
    container.append(select);

    select.find('option').each(function (optionIndex, optionElement) {
      var radioGroup = select.attr('id') + "Group";
      var label = $("<label />");
      container.append(label);

      $("<input type='radio' name='" + radioGroup + "' />")
          .attr("value", $(this).val())
          //.click((function () { select.val($(this).val()); })) //radio updates select - see optional below
          .appendTo(label);

      $("<span>" + $(this).val() + "</span>").appendTo(label);
    });

    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957207/how-to-check-uncheck-radio-button-on-click
    //optional - this logic handles unchecking when clicking on an already checked radio
    container.find(":radio + span").mousedown(
      function (e) {
        var $span = $(this);
        var $radio = $($span.prev());
        if ($radio.is(':checked')) {
          var uncheck = function() {
            setTimeout(function () { $radio.prop('checked', false); }, 0);
          };
          var unbind = function() {
            $span.unbind('mouseup', up);
          };
          var up = function() {
            uncheck();
            unbind();
          };
          $span.bind('mouseup', up);
          $span.one('mouseout', unbind);
        } else {
          select.val($radio.val());
        }
      }
    );

    select.change((function () { //select updates radio
      $("input[name='" + select.attr('id') + "Group" + "'][value='" + this.value + "']").prop("checked", true);
    }));
  });
});
```

```css
/* http://jsfiddle.net/496c9/ */
 .radioSelectContainer > select {
     /*display: none;*/
}
.radioSelectContainer > label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0.3em 0.3em 0 0;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
}
.radioSelectContainer > label > span {
    padding:0.2em;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}
.radioSelectContainer > label > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}
.radioSelectContainer > label > input:checked + span {
    background-color:#404040;
    color:#F7F7F7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="radioSelect" id="sizeOptions">
    <option value="S">S</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option value="L">L</option>
    <option value="XL">XL</option>
    <option value="2XL">2XL</option>
    <option value="3XL">3XL</option>
    <option value="4XL">4XL</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your option text and value are the same. What do you want the button text to be???

Comment: Also please use jquery 3.6 and change bind to on or use toggleClass

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan for the reply.  I am planning to change the update jquery, but nor right now in order to review the site first after change.  As for the text to be, I need something different,,  like `Option 1`, `Option 2`.. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2bok3gn1/

```
const sizes = {"S":"Small","M":"Medium"...."4XL":"Huge"}
```

and

```
$("<span>" + sizes[$(this).val()] + "</span>").appendTo(label);
```

Comment: So I replace `.attr("value", $(this).val())` with `.attr("value", sizes[$(this).val()])`.  But where to add `const sizes = {"S":"Small","M":"Medium","4XL":"Huge"]`?  Can you edit the jsfiddle or code, or tell me where to add it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried, but the buttons disappeared: http://jsfiddle.net/kptagsqo/

Comment: Np, thanks.  But now it doesn't auto change the adjacent drop down list with the button.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2bok3gn1/

Comment: Great, thanks.  Another thing if possible: (1) where can I add a `<br>` or `\n` so the created buttons start under the dropdown list (beside each other), and not beside the dropdown list? (2) I also noticed that when I click the button, it jumps to the top of the page (http://jsfiddle.net/o2qre97p/1/).

Comment: Just add a br:  `container.append(select);  container.append('<br/>');` - I don't see any jumping

Comment: You've been so patient, thanks a lot.  This is the final step so the script can be usable: When I click any one the new buttons, the page jumps to the top.  How can it be fixed so it stays where it is? (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o2qre97p/1/).

Comment: `position:absolute;   top:-20px; ` is the problem. How to solve it is a new question