# What is .previous method and is it jQuery or core JS or some other library?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have encountered this solution for a problem I tried to solve (uncheck radio buttons), which works perfectly, but I can't find anywhere on google what does `.previous` do and is it JS core or some library?

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    if (this.previous) {
        this.checked = false;
    }
    this.previous = this.checked;
});
```

this is [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4957207/747024)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've quoted isn't anything I'm familiar with. The [`prev` *method*](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) is jQuery-specific. It gives you the previous sibling element. The DOM equivalent *property* is [`previousSibling`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-640FB3C8) (which may not be an Element, it may be a text node or something else).

It looks there like someone's creating an [expando property](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Expando_Properties) on the element. I would strongly recommend against an expando property called `previous`, but there you go.

Answer (score 2):

You can add any variable to an existing object, in this case the input type radio gets another property called previous. Its part of the core javascript.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($(this).prev()) { ...
```

You could try use the above.
http://api.jquery.com/prev/