# unable to uncheck the radiobutton

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Hi when i click the radion button ,It always checked.I cannot uncheck the radion button am serching and try [How to check/uncheck radio button on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957207/how-to-check-uncheck-radio-button-on-click/6246260#6246260) this link.

**problems**

I can check  only once,once i click uncheck it always uncheck cannot work properly 
code

```
  <input value='' type='radio' id='one' onClick="getCurrentLocation()"/>

   $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){

    if (this.previous) {
        this.checked = false;
    }
    this.previous = this.checked;
});
```

Comment: Strange but above code works for me in ff, chrome,ie9. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qegLN/)

Comment: I have updated my answer with jQuery code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it your the only radio button?

Radio buttons vere developed for keeping one of possible states from the set.

**So if there is only one radio button - change it with checkbox.**

**If you have several of them - choose some default one for unchecking currently selected.**
But if you click on another radio from the set, it will became checked without need of special code.

(As far as I remember, there was no way to uncheck radio-button in browser with mouse click on it, so I don't expect such behavour from scripts as well)

***For checkbox you don't need special code to uncheck it on click - it's default behavour for them in all browsers!***

If it's only dessign question, then you can use IMG of empty and checked radio buttons, and onClick change the image. In this case you can keep your state in hidden input field.

But it will be confusing for your users...

Comment: What is your task? What you sure the radio button is nessesary there?

Comment: when i click radio button it always check i cannot uncheck it again

Comment: <input name="myname" value='' type='checkbox' /> try checkbox for your task!

Comment: @ Danei know Check box but i need radio button only

Comment: But why you want radio-button for task which is for check-box?!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11767/discussion-between-user1324068-and-danesoul)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use same `name` property `input`.

example:

```
<input name="myname" value='' type='radio' id='one' onClick="getCurrentLocation()"/>
<input name="myname" value='' type='radio' id='two' onClick="getCurrentLocation()"/>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b6Pn4/)**

As you need single check at a time, so it would be better to use checkbox.

```
<input name="myname" value='' type='checkbox' id='one' onClick="getCurrentLocation()"/>
<input name="myname" value='' type='checkbox' id='two' onClick="getCurrentLocation()"/>
```

Comment: i need single radio button only

Comment: if you need single, you need check-bock, not radio button

Answer (score 0):

That's how they work. Radio buttons should be user in groups, where you choose between them. If you want a single button that you can toggle, use a checkbox.

If you are trying to mimic a checkbox using a radio button, you will just confuse your users.

Comment: For checkbox you don't need special code to uncheck it on click - it's default behavour for them in all browsers!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

markup:

```
<input value='' type='radio' id='one' onClick="getCurrentLocation()"/>
```

jQuery,

```
var flag = 0;
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    if(flag === 0)
    {
      $(this).prop('checked', true);              
      flag = 1;
    }
    else if(flag == 1)
    {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
      flag = 0;        
    }

});
```

​

Since you're using an `id` and have only one radio button call it directly, you don't need to use `this`

Although, I'd recommend you use `checkbox` like the others have.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MWNWL/1/)