# input type radio button checked else statement not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a class in the parent wrapper of radio button, I did so , it is working but else statement is not workin

Here is my code

```
<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="name[]" checked>
</div>

<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="name[]">
</div>
```

This is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
      $(this).parent().addClass('new')
    }
    else {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('new')
    }
  });
})
```

I want to remove the class new when the radio button is not checked, but it is not working.
e.g.
http://codepen.io/amitabha197/pen/KzqvWv

Comment: Sorry for late reply as I was outstation after I asked this question. I really thank to all of you who have ever helped me, made me learn where I was wrong. I have read the entire conversation in this page. Thanks to all for this help. I know this by using custom radio btn css but for my project it's a bit worry so i chosen jquery for it. All the codes of @Asad, Reddy & Webeno's code also working are working but I have chosen Reddy's for simple chaining. I have updated my codepen http://codepen.io/amitabha197/pen/KzqvWv ,  Again thanks to everyone for your co-operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After  **webeno** and **mhodges** pointed me to the right direction here is my solution.

```
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('new').siblings().removeClass('new');        
  });
```

---

Also point to remember, If at all you had been trying to uncheck a single radio button then know this.

**You cannot uncheck a radio button**. All the clicks you do on it will keep it checked, **Use checkbox instead.**

**[Why is it impossible to deselect HTML “radio” inputs?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13511/why-is-it-impossible-to-deselect-html-radio-inputs)**

**[Unable to uncheck radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764384/2592042)**

Comment: I don't think that's true, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120576/how-to-uncheck-checked-radio-button...

Comment: @webeno it is, you cannot uncheck a radio button by mouse clicks as you do with check boxes, But using jquery and stuff there are work arounds to make it look like uncheck by replacing it with new element, but the truth is you cannot uncheck it.

Comment: there you go, it IS possible via jQuery, and this is a question tagged with jQuery...

Comment: the answer with the highest score explains how you can do it using pure javascript, actually...

Comment: @webeno his question is not `how to uncheck a radio button` his problem is that his else condition is not executing.  How will it execute  if the click on radio button  keeps it checked all the time?? And I dont think he has to replace the radio button and stuff its off topic here

Comment: Downvoters please comment my mistake. I don't think this answer is wrong.

Comment: You all didn't even read the question. The OP is trying to remove the class from all radio buttons that are unchecked and add the class to the one that just got checked. He's not trying to programmatically uncheck the radio button... /facepalm

Comment: @Reddy Downvoter here: Your answer has nothing to do with the question. "I want to remove the class new when the radio button is not checked, but it is not working."

Comment: @mhodges he is using click event and in his if he is checking with `$(this)`. So when ever the radio button is clicked it always checked.. you cannot uncheck it... OP problem is he is clicking it second time and he wants to remove the classs which will not work on radio buttons

Comment: @Reddy Like i said, you didn't read the question. He wants to ADD the class to the newly checked radio button parent, and he wants to REMOVE the class from all of the other (unchecked) radio button parents. His logic is correct, he just needed to throw it in an iterator over all of the radio buttons

Comment: @Reddy you're stuck at your idea of the OP wanting to uncheck the radio button - that's not what they want. They simply want a class to be added to the checked radio button, so one would *always* be checked, actually... and by the way, with radio buttons, there will *always* be some, if not more, unselected (if one is selected)... ;)

Comment: @mhodges Thanks for your patience, But I dont see anywhere in his question saying he wanted to remove class from all the radio buttons. I am damn sure that he is trying to check and uncheck the same radio button.

Comment: @webeno Yes thats what I mean, But then why is he not iterating over other elements?

Comment: @Reddy "I want to add a class in the parent wrapper of radio button (...) I want to remove the class new when the radio button is not checked" - what is unclear here?

Comment: @Reddy Because the OP is obviously new to jQuery and doesn't fully understand how to approach the issue, which is why they posted the question.. OP's expressed needs > their code

Comment: @webeno you guys were right, I understood that after I saw his codepen. If not for that I would have sat down for an argument for another few hours :D

Comment: @Reddy nice one for admitting that! ;)

Comment: @mhodges I updated my answer, If you think it right you can remove the downvote.

Comment: I'll remove the downvote because you have joined us on the dark side ;) but I would just like to point out that your solution requires very specific code hierarchy/structure, which is typically not a good idea for code reuse/modularity.

Comment: @mhodges I don't see why your solution is more scalable, can you explain?

Comment: @mhodges you are right about the hierarchy though, And I see your solution would handle the hierarchy better. But Ill go with this solution, Others have already put there logic's, Also I think the OP's  div's will be wrapped under same parent.

Comment: @webeno it allows for the DOM structure to change rather drastically and remains working, is all. It's not reliant on any specific structure

Comment: We way over thought this ;)

Comment: @mhodges is it not? so why do you use `closest(".radio")`? because you have to :) you have to have a certain structure, the code cannot guess what you want :)

Comment: @mhodges I would like to point one drawback in your code. `$('input[type="radio"]:checked')` will select all the elements in the page which are checked. That is not good :) you might have to change it to target only that specific radio button

Comment: @webeno Correction, *much less* reliant on specific DOM structure, of course you need at least something concrete to code against.

Comment: @Reddy Yeah agreed, if he had given more context, I would have limited the selector or used the context parameter in the selector to just the container in question. We were given so little, it's hard to code around anything like that. Tit for tat, honestly, because your solution would remove the "new" class from all siblings, which aren't guaranteed to be radio button containers. Other radio buttons in the same group may be in a different container on the page as well.. You just never know with this. Lets just stop over-thinking this, it's getting ridiculous lol. OP Got what they need

Comment: @mhodges yes true. I still wonder why didnt ths chat prompt for a continue discussion in chat room

Comment: @Reddy Edited my solution

Answer (score 0):

## Edited

For code optimization & modularity.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function(){
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    $('input[type="radio"][name="'+name+'"]').closest(".radio").removeClass("new");
    $(this).closest(".radio").addClass("new");
  });
});
```

Comment: But then `$('input[type="radio"][name="'+name+'"]:checked')` will always be equal to `$(this)` as this is the one which is checked and has triggered the event.

Answer (score 0):

use this function will solve you problem

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('new');
    $('input[type="radio"]').not(this).parent().removeClass('new');
  });
});
```

Comment: is there problem with this @Amitabha ?

Answer (score 0):

You can include [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element as parent of `<input type="radio">` elements at `html`.

> The *HTML Label Element* (`<label>`) represents a caption for an item
>   in a user interface. It can be associated with a control either by
>   placing the control element inside the `<label>` element, or by using
>   the for attribute. Such a control is called the *labeled control* of
>   the label element. One input can be associated with multiple labels.

The parent `label` element will be associated with `:checked` first child descendant `input`.

You can style `css` `:after` pseudo element compounded to `:checked` selector to display blue `border` when `input` element is `:checked`.

```css
div.radio {
  display: inline-block;
}
label.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
label.radio > :checked:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  left: -6px;
  top: -4px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="name[]" checked>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" for="radio2" name="name[]">
  </label>
</div>
```

---

If requirement is to use existing `html`, `jQuery`, you can utilize `.click()`, `.toggleCLass()` to add, remove `"new"` `className` if descendant `input` element `checked` property is `false` at `click` event, set `input` `checked` property to `true`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var radio = $(".radio");
  radio.click(function(e) {
    var input = e.target.querySelector("input[type=radio]");
    if (!input.checked) {
      radio.toggleClass("new");
      input.checked = true;
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.new {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="radio new">
  <input type="radio" name="name[]" checked>
</div>

<div class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="name[]">
</div>
```