# Trying to uncheck a radio button

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to uncheck a radio button, but strangely it does not seem to be working.

**code is below**

```
$('#hkitdyn15').attr("checked",false);
```

**This also does not work**

```
$('#hkitdyn15').prop("checked",false);
```

**This also does not work**

```
$('#hkitdyn15').removeAttr("checked");
```

**On page load my radio button is generated as an image but it still has the checked attribute**

```
<img id="hkitdyn15" style="width: 17px; height: 12px;" src="htmlkit/enabled_radio_checked.gif" checked="false">

<input id="hkitdyn14" class="radio" type="radio" value="checkToRetrieveMessageNames" name="bulkGroup" style="float: left; display: none;">
```

any ideas?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?  Show us some of your HTML

Comment: You'll need to show us your HTML, because that code should be working. Perhaps your selector is wrong?

Comment: Have you specified the id as hkitdyn15 for your radio button?

Comment: hi, pls check thru again if you are accessing right element.

Comment: yeah the id for me gets generated automatically and that is the ID given

Comment: @ShamariCampbell in that case your ID will be different each time you regenerate HTML, I have a strong feeling of you accessing wrong element.

Comment: @Aman yeah that is true but it is the same ID each time (unless i add any new components to my page)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery How to Uncheck A radio button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117538/jquery-how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check/uncheck radio button on click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957207/how-to-check-uncheck-radio-button-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

As `#hkitdyn15` is represents an image and following statement is working just fine.

```
$('#hkitdyn15').removeAttr("checked");
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/VWwMN/)**

But if you want to change `checked` state of the `radio` then:

```
$('#hkitdyn14').prop("checked", false);
```

***OR***

```
$('#hkitdyn14').removeAttr("checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` is `hkitdyn14`, not `hkitdyn15`. Use this:

```
$('#hkitdyn14').attr("checked",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're referencing the wrong id. Your image has the id "hkitdyn15", not the radio button.
You need to be using the "hkitdyn14" id. Try any of the following:

```
$('#hkitdyn14').prop("checked",false);

$('#hkitdyn14').attr("checked",false);

$('#hkitdyn14').removeAttr("checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to log your element before removing the checked

```
console.log($('#hkitdyn15'));
```

Maybe your radio image wasnt created  when you load the script

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a name attribute to your radio button.

For example :

`<input type="radio" id="hkitdyn14" name="hkitdyn14" checked="checked" style="display:none;" />`

and then

`$('input[name=hkitdyn14]').removeAttr('checked');`

Take a look at this JsFidlle, it's a complete example of what you want to do : http://jsfiddle.net/EsXwp/