# Radio Buttons clear check when clicked again

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have a set of three radio buttons and they have mutual exclusion in them, as I implemented group name property, but the problem is, in the initial stage, none of the radio button is selected,[image]

But when I select any of the radio button, then I cannot deselect the same, although mutual exclusion is in progress, but I want them to deselect as well.

[image]

My code aspx is:

```
<td>
<asp:RadioButton ID="AChk" runat="server" CssClass="itemRightAlign" GroupName="A"/>
</td>
<td>
<asp:RadioButton ID="DChk" runat="server" CssClass="itemRightAlign" GroupName="A"/>
</td>
<td>
<asp:RadioButton ID="WChk" runat="server" CssClass="itemRightAlign" GroupName="A"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Similar question & potential solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957207/how-to-check-uncheck-radio-button-on-click).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have both a code problem and a misunderstanding.

The misunderstanding is about how the mutual exclusion radio buttons work (or are supposed to work) (or are expected by the users to work).

The code problem is that in a mutually exclusion radio buttons group you need to initially select one of them.

So, I believe there are two ways of solving the problem:

1. Keep the radio buttons groud. Add a "none" button to the set, so that it works as if none of the other three are selected. And initially select this "none" button.
2. change the radio buttons to check boxes, so the user might select *and* deselect each of them. Then implement your own exclusion logic. I don't recommend this one.

Comment: Well for checkbox I need mutual exclusion and for that I need to use Ajax checkbox mutual extender.  :(, so I will go with first solution.:)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use javascript...

doing binding in jquery, it's easier, and the name= should match your rendered groupname "name=" attribute...

```
var lastChecked = null;
$('input[name=A]').click(function(){
  if (lastChecked == this) {
    this.checked = false;
    lastChecked = null;
  }
  lastChecked = this;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. You might want to edit the first line to be `=` rather than `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to deselect:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('A');
for(var i=0; i<radios.length; i++)
{
    radios[i].checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deselect a radio button by using the attribute `ondblclick`.

```
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1
" value="1" ondblclick="uncheckRadio();">
    Apple</label>
```

When you double click on the radio button, just call a javascript function to set the `checked` property to false.

```
function uncheckRadio() {
 var choice = document.form1.RadioGroup1;
 for (i = 0; i < choice.length; i++) {
  if ( choice[i].checked = true ) 
   choice[i].checked = false; 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar implementation using the attribute `ondblclick`and jQuery.  Also, this will allow you to include this functionality within controls with a dynamically generated client ID.

Code behind:

```
foreach (ListItem li in rbl.Items)
    li.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", string.Format("clearCurrentRadioButtonSelection(\"{0}\")", rbl.UniqueID));
```

ASPX page

```
function clearCurrentRadioButtonSelection(controlName) {
    var id = "input[name=" + controlName + "]";

    $(id).each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    });
}
```