# Mutually exclusive checkboxes per row rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a rails site that communicates with a backend service which returns a list of some set of objects.  The UI then prints out the list of objects values in a table and allows the user to reject or approve the rows with an approval and denial checkbox for each row.  I was wondering if there was a way to only allow one checkbox to be checked at a time since they should be mutually exclusive.  View code is below

```
<td><%= check_box_tag 'approve_request_ids[]', e.request_id %></td>
<td><%= check_box_tag 'decline_request_ids[]', e.request_id %></td>
```

Comment: Radio buttons are what you want.

Comment: But radio buttons do not allow a user to unselect one once they have selected them without refreshing

Comment: You can add a `none` or similar option.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using jquery like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>  
    <td><%= check_box_tag 'approve_request_ids[]', e.request_id %></td>
    <td><%= check_box_tag 'decline_request_ids[]', e.request_id %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Your Jquery:

```
$('tr .checkbox').click(function () {
  var state = $(this).prop("checked");
  $(this)
      .parent()
      .parent()
      .find('input.checkbox:checked')
      .prop("checked", false);

  $(this).prop("checked", state);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> a way to only allow one checkbox to be checked at a time

My initial thoughts were *use a radio button* instead - and as per the comments, you'll want to make a provision to have the button "deselected", which you'd achieve with JS.

Let me detail how you'd do this, and also how you'd handle the checkboxes:

--

**Radio Buttons**

You *could* use Radio buttons - you'd have to make it so if you clicked on one which was "selected", JQuery would "deselect" it:

[How to check/uncheck radio button on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957207/how-to-check-uncheck-radio-button-on-click)

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RuwrL/)

```
#app/views/controller/your_view.html.erb
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female</td>
    </tr>
</table>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("tr").on("mousedown", ":radio", function(){
  var $self = $(this);
  if( $self.is(':checked') ){
    var uncheck = function(){
      setTimeout(function(){$self.removeAttr('checked');},0);
    };
    var unbind = function(){
      $self.unbind('mouseup',up);
    };
    var up = function(){
      uncheck();
      unbind();
    };
    $self.bind('mouseup',up);
    $self.one('mouseout', unbind);
  }
});
```

--

**Checkboxes**

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3NYEm/)

The *checkbox* can be "unchecked" with JS - what you'd have to do is catch the "check" action with JS, and then "uncheck" the corresponding checkbox for that row. This will ensure you can only select one checkbox, whilst provisioning for "none" selection:

```
#Table same setup as Tiago Farias


#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("tr").on("change", ":checkbox", function(){
   if( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
       $(this).parent().parent().find(":checkbox").not($(this)).attr('checked', false);
   }
});
```